# find and replace string (regex) across multiple files in linux using sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have a list of files with strings like `{{abc-exfs-value}}`. The sub string abc differs in each of the file. For example, a regex search (java) like: `\{\{*-exfs-value\}\}` will return all the strings that is of concern here. How to proceed on replacing all those strings that match the regex pattern in files in linux?

I am able to get the list of files using  `grep -R '\-exfs\-value' .`. Using sed how to replace the strings?

Comment: What do you want to replace it with?

Comment: Have you tried anything already? This sounds like a simple `sed 's/pattern/replacement/'`.

Comment: {{abc-exfs-value}} with {{xyz-exfs-value}}. The many variations in abc with a 'xyz'.

Comment: The "abc" part, is that only letters? Are there numbers? Are there other symbols?

Comment: Use `sed 's/\({{\)[^-]*\(-.*}}\)/\1xyz\2/'`

Comment: How about `({{).*?(-exfs-value}})` with `\1xyz\2`

Comment: @glennjackman its alphanumeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think this is what's needed:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\({{\)[[:alnum:]]\+\(-exfs-value}}\)/\1xyz\2/g' file1 file2 ...
```

Comment: sed must be old school, forces you to escape metachars?

Comment: Indeed: https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Regular-expression-syntaxes.html#Regular-expression-syntaxes

Comment: @sln `sed` by default uses `BRE` hence the need for escaping meta-characters. Depending on the version of your `sed` you can enable `ERE` by doing `-E` (BSD) or `-r` (GNU). There is another variant of `sed` called super-sed or `ssed` which supports `PCRE` if you enable `-R` option.